# Using pymc3 to fit lomax model

Tags: bayesian, pymc3

I have a pretty simple example that doesn't seem to work. My goal is to build a Lomax model, and since PyMC3 doesn't have a Lomax distribution I use the fact that an Exponential mixed with a Gamma is a Lomax (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lomax_distribution#Gamma-exponential_mixture)):

```
import pymc3 as pm
from scipy.stats import lomax

# Generate artificial data with a shape and scale parameterization
data = lomax.rvs(c=2.5, scale=3, size=1000)

# if t ~ Exponential(lamda) and lamda ~ Gamma(shape, rate), then t ~ Lomax(shape, rate)
with pm.Model() as hierarchical:
    shape = pm.Uniform('shape', 0, 10)
    rate = pm.Uniform('rate', 0 , 10)
    lamda = pm.Gamma('lamda', alpha=shape, beta=rate)
    t = pm.Exponential('t', lam=lamda, observed=data)
    trace = pm.sample(1000, tune=1000)
```

The summary is:

```
>>> pm.summary(trace)
           mean        sd  mc_error   hpd_2.5  hpd_97.5   n_eff      Rhat
shape  4.259874  2.069418  0.060947  0.560821  8.281654  1121.0  1.001785
rate   6.532874  2.399463  0.068837  2.126299  9.998271  1045.0  1.000764
lamda  0.513459  0.015924  0.000472  0.483754  0.545652  1096.0  0.999662
```

I would expect the shape and rate estimates to be close to 2.5 and 3 respectively. I tried various non-informative priors for shape and rate, including `pm.HalfFlat()` and `pm.Uniform(0, 100)` but both resulted in worse fits. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out: To derive a lomax from an exponential-gamma mixture, I need to specify a `lamda` for each example in the dataset (`lamda = pm.Gamma('lamda', alpha=shape, beta=rate, shape=len(data)`). This is because the model assumes each subject in the data has its own `lamda_i` where `lamda_i ~ Gamma(shape, rate)` for every `i`.